Submit for Login Review(Some of the permissions below have not been approved)
We are using Facebook Login and public_profile advanced access for an iOS app. All reviews are done and on the dashboard there is nothing to submit for a review, all green lights(Business Review is done). When we try to login via an account which has a role on the meta developer "published"(live in old terminology) app, we are seeing the warning below.

Submit for Login Review
Some of the permission below have not been approved for use by Facebook.
Submit for review now or learn more
If you are not using Limited Login, you will need to hand all Graph API calls using Graph API, IOS. The access token will not be valid. To learn more about changes to the Facebook SDK for iOS and how you can continue using the Facebook Login SDK, visit the blog.

Issue is that, when you click on Submit for a Review on the warning, it takes you to App Review tab on the meta developers dashboard which does not have anything to submit for a review and everything looks ok.
Anyone has ever seen this? How did you solve the issue? Thanks for the help!
We have doubled checked that app is only using login and public_profile. We are on the newest SDK due to Privacy Manifest requirements of the iOS that is why we are using Limited Login on iOS as well. Normally we should not see this warning but it keeps showing up. I could not find much at the internet regarding the note about "Graph API". Not sure if we somehow call Graph API still but since SDK is updated, this should not happened. How can we check this and make sure that we are not using Limited Login properly or still using Graph API somewhere?
